# Swift - Sticky header with UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to develop a header with a `scrollView` a bit like the Revolut app:

[image: Revolut app screen recording]

I was thinking of adding one `scrollview` into another but I guess wouldn't get the same result.

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import SnapKit

class ItemDetailViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {
        
        
        lazy var topBar = CryptoDetailTopBarView()
        lazy var header = UIView()
        lazy var chartView = UIView()
        
        lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
            let view = UIScrollView()
            view.contentSize = CGSize(width: 414, height: 2000)
            view.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
            view.bounces = true
            return view
        }()
        
        lazy var name = UILabel()
        lazy var symbol = UILabel()
        lazy var type = UILabel()
        
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            view.backgroundColor = .systemGray
            
            view.addSubview(topBar)
            view.addSubview(header)
            view.addSubview(scrollView)
            
            header.addSubview(name)
            header.addSubview(symbol)
            header.addSubview(type)
            
            scrollView.addSubview(chartView)
            
            topBar.layer.zPosition = 20
            topBar.backgroundColor = .blue
            
            header.backgroundColor = .systemRed
            
            name.textColor = .label
            name.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 34)
            
            symbol.textColor = .label
            type.textColor = .systemGray
            
            
            chartView.backgroundColor = .white
            chartView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    
            self.topBar.title.text = "Title"
            self.name.text = "Title"
            self.symbol.text = "Text"
            self.type.text = "Type"
    
            
            scrollView.delegate = self
            
            updateViewConstraints()
        }
        
        func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
            
            if header.frame.minY < topBar.frame.maxY - name.frame.minY - name.frame.height/2 {
                topBar.title.alpha = 1
            } else {
                topBar.title.alpha = 0
            }
            
            let y: CGFloat = scrollView.contentOffset.y
            
            header.snp.remakeConstraints { make in
                make.left.equalToSuperview()
                make.top.equalTo(topBar.snp.bottom).inset(y)
                make.width.equalToSuperview()
                make.height.equalTo(150)
            }
            
        }
        
        
        override func updateViewConstraints() {
            
            topBar.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.left.top.equalToSuperview()
                make.width.equalToSuperview()
                make.height.equalTo(90)
            }
            
            header.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.left.equalToSuperview()
                make.top.equalTo(topBar.snp.bottom)
                make.width.equalToSuperview()
                make.height.equalTo(150)
            }
            
            scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(header.snp.bottom)
                make.centerX.bottom.width.equalToSuperview()
            }
            
            name.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalToSuperview().offset(10)
                make.left.equalToSuperview().offset(16)
                make.width.equalTo(200)
                make.height.equalTo(41)
            }
            
            symbol.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(name.snp.bottom).offset(10)
                make.left.equalTo(name)
                make.width.equalTo(50)
                make.height.equalTo(20)
            }
            
            type.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.top.equalTo(symbol)
                make.left.equalTo(symbol.snp.right).offset(10)
                make.width.equalTo(50)
                make.height.equalTo(20)
            }
            
            chartView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
                make.left.equalTo(scrollView).offset(16)
                make.width.equalTo(scrollView).offset(-32)
                make.top.equalTo(15)
                make.height.equalTo(100)
            }
            
            
            super.updateViewConstraints()
        }
        
        fileprivate func getHeightOfHeaderView() -> CGFloat {
            return header.frame.height
        }
        
    }
```

The `topBar` view is the `view` with the smaller title that replace the big title when I scroll down (like Revolut).

I'm updating constraints using `SnapKit` depending on my `scrollView` offset.

Here is what I get:

[image: My app screen recording]

You can see that my white `view` called `chartView` (part of the `scrollView`) is moving faster than my header which remove the "pushing" effect there is on Revolut.

Also, my white `view` is stuck when I drag down the `scrollView`: there should be a "pulling down" effect.

Basically I want to make the same thing as Revolut. The App Store has the pretty same header for non featured app.

I tried with collectionView, tableView and scrollView (using navigation bar big title) but it's not doing what I want. I need to make it myself from scratch like Revolut did I think.

Btw, you can easily execute my code because there is no storyboard needed.

Comment: Instead of adding your header as a subview, use the tableview's built in header instead. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/views_and_controls/table_views/adding_headers_and_footers_to_table_sections

Comment: Can I make it sticky on top? I guess using a subview gives me more flexibility.

Comment: Yes, you can! That's what it's designed for.

Comment: No it's not. It's designed to be sticked to the first cell that belongs to it.

Comment: Sorry. I assumed table views had a sticky header feature because collection views do. Maybe change it to a collection view? It was able to do something like [this](https://github.com/aheze/DeveloperAssets/blob/master/StickyHeaderCollectionView.gif) with just `sectionHeader.pinToVisibleBounds = true`

Comment: No it is not good, I hardly tried with available views but it's not working. I have to make it myself.

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented something like this a couple of times and you're really close.

Reacting to `scrollViewDidScroll` is the right thing to do, but I wouldn't recommend updating the constraints. I would't say that Auto Layout was designed to be updated in real time, and even if it worked correctly, you'll probably see a performance impact.

Instead, use the `transform` property of your view.

You'll have to tweak the values but it should look a bit like this:

```
header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translateX: 0, y: max(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y - header.bounds.y))
```

The reasoning for this math is simpler than it seems:

We want our view to be moved downwards as soon as the content offset reaches our view's position. This happens when `scrollView.contentOffset.y - header.bounds.y == 0`. Before this happens, this number will be lower than 0, that's why we use `max`. This way, before this happens, we'll apply a transform with a translation of 0, so our view will be dragged normally.

Once our scroll view has been dragged beyond the point where our view is at the top, that's when we want to make it sticky. `scrollView.contentOffset.y - header.bounds.y` tells us how far beyond our view the user has scrolled, so move our view down by exactly that value.

If you are using a view with content insets, you might need to tweak your math, it *might* look something like this, but if it doesn't work I'll leave it up to you to play with the values to see what works.

```
header.transform = CGAffineTransform(translateX: 0, y: max(0, scrollView.contentOffset.y - (header.bounds.y + scrollView.adjustedContentInsets.top)))
```

Tip: Use a print statement with values like the content offset on `scrollViewDidScroll` in order to figure out what numbers you want exactly.

Comment: Can you explain me why I shouldn't update constraints?

Comment: And is it possible to translate to a precise y rather than what happens here:  y +/- k ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use large navigation bar for the title effect, with UITableView / UICollectionView headers.

**EDITED**:
You can use a blur effect on navigation bar, like this:

```
let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
// iOS13 and later:
let statusBarHeight = view.window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height ?? 0
// the size of the blur effect
let bounds = navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds.insetBy(dx: 0, dy: -(statusBarHeight)).offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: -(statusBarHeight))
// Create blur effect.
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .light))
blurEffectView.frame = bounds
// Set navigation bar up.
navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(blurEffectView)
navigationController?.navigationBar.sendSubview(toBack: blurEffectView)
```

Comment: Yeah but how can I do this menu with blur background "merging" to the default navigation bar when scrolling ?

Comment: @PaulBénéteau you can add a blur effect as subview to the navigation bar, and the items will be blurred under the nav bar.

Comment: Edited my post with an example